# Magento 2 : custom changes in product details page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4

I want to do some custom changes in the product details page,

for example :  I want to get custom attribute value in the product details page,
how can i do that?
please advise me on this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> **Here below file show your custom attribute into product details page.**

**app/code/Vendorename/Modulename/view/frontend/layout**

**catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
      <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
          <block class="Vendorename\Modulename\Block\Customblock"
                 name="custom.file.attribute"
                 after="product.info.price"
                 template="Vendorename_Modulename::customfile.phtml" />
      </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Vendorename/Modulename/view/frontend/templates**

**customfile.phtml**

```
<?php

$prd = $block->getCurrentProduct();

$prd_attribute = $prd->getAttributeText('Custom_attribute_name'); 

echo "<h1>".$prd_attribute."</h1>";

?>
```

**app/code/Vendorename/Modulename/Block**

**Customblock.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendorename\Modulename\Block;

class Customblock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }
    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {
        return $this->registry->registry('current_product');
    }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***